# How to perform click function on item of a Flatlist in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am getting list of data and i want to display detail of each data when click on any item of flat list here is my code.

```
 <FlatList style={{paddingBottom:5}}
          data = {this.state.fetchFreelancer}
          keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>

          <FreelancerCategory

          imageUrifreelancer = {{uri: `${item.profile_img}`}}
          imageUrifeatured = {{uri: `${item.badge.badget_url}`}}
          featuredColor ={`${entities.decode(item.badge.badget_color)}`}
          flagimageUri= {{uri: `${item.location.flag}`}}
          freelancername={`${entities.decode(item.name)}`}
          title={`${entities.decode(item._tag_line)}`}
          rate={`${entities.decode(item._perhour_rate)}`}
          country={`${entities.decode(item.location._country)}`}
          />
```

But i am not able to perform onPress in flat list can any one please help me regarding this. Thanks

It is not working..

```
<FlatList
                style={{ paddingBottom: 5 }}
                data={this.state.fetchFreelancer}
                keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                 onPress={() => navigate('DetailFreelancerScreen', {profile_id: item.profile_id})}
                //  onPress={() => alert('Item pressed')}
                  >
                    <FreelancerCategory
                      imageUrifreelancer={{ uri: `${item.profile_img}` }}
                      imageUrifeatured={{ uri: `${item.badge.badget_url}` }}
                      featuredColor={`${entities.decode(
                        item.badge.badget_color
                      )}`}
                      flagimageUri={{ uri: `${item.location.flag}` }}
                      freelancername={`${entities.decode(item.name)}`}
                      title={`${entities.decode(item._tag_line)}`}
                      rate={`${entities.decode(item._perhour_rate)}`}
                      country={`${entities.decode(item.location._country)}`}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
              />
```

Comment: You can wrap your `<FreelancerCategory>` with a `<TouchableOpacity>` and pass it an onPress prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist . This article will help you out how to properly use the `FlatList` component. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform click events, you should cover your items with TouchableOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback.

```
<FlatList 
    style={{paddingBottom:5}}
    data = {this.state.fetchFreelancer}
    keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailFreelancerScreen', 
               {profile_id: item.profile_id})}
        >
           <FreelancerCategory
             imageUrifreelancer = {{uri: `${item.profile_img}`}}
             imageUrifeatured = {{uri: `${item.badge.badget_url}`}}
             featuredColor ={`${entities.decode(item.badge.badget_color)}`}
             flagimageUri= {{uri: `${item.location.flag}`}}
             freelancername={`${entities.decode(item.name)}`}
             title={`${entities.decode(item._tag_line)}`}
             rate={`${entities.decode(item._perhour_rate)}`}
             country={`${entities.decode(item.location._country)}`}
          /> 
       </TouchableOpacity>
      );
  />
```

for more info refer the RN [official document](http://%20https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)

Comment: I have did it alert is working but navigator is not working

Comment: which navigator are you using? version??

Comment: I am not sure about version @Banid

Comment: That's ok,  which navigator ? React Navigation ?

Comment: use  **this.props.navigation.navigate**, not navigate. I have updated the answer,

Comment: Still Nothing :(

Comment: Make sure the route names are correct. Make a snack so I can reproduce this problem.